# How to change @keyframes vlaues using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am wanting to do is to change the top value of 0% and 100% of the `@keyframes` depending on what x equals in javascript.

I have changed css using javascript before but i am stuck on this one

**Code:**

```js
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1080) + 1);
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}


@keyframes example {
    0%   {left:0px; top:300px}
    100% {left:830px; top:0px}
}
```

```html
 <div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider CSS variables and you can easily do this:

```js
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
console.log(x);
var root = document.querySelector(':root');
root.style.setProperty("--top",x+"px");
```

```css
:root {
  --top: 0;
}

div.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    top: var(--top);
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```